# Contact form issue sending email from local host (IIS) to my hotmail in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have designed a simple contact form using Visual studio 2005,the page runs fine but when I hit send button I get error as showing below: error in " mailclient.Send(message).I would like to send it from my localhost that Im using with visual studio to my hotmail account but it's not sending email to my hotmail account the error is as follow.

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond  
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Source Error: 

Line 24:         Dim mailclient As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient
Line 25:         mailclient.Host = mailServerName
Line 26:         mailclient.Send(message)
Line 27:         message.Dispose()
Line 28:     End Sub
```

and this is my controller class :

```
Imports System.Net.Mail


Partial Class ContactUs
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub textComments_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub textComments_TextChanged1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtComments.TextChanged
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Send_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSend.Click
        SendMail(txtEmail.Text, txtComments.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendMail(ByVal From As String, ByVal body As String)
        Dim mailServerName As String = "mail.hotmail.com"
        Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(From, "Myaddress@hotmail.com", "Feedback", body)
        Dim mailclient As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient
        mailclient.Host = mailServerName
        mailclient.Send(message)
        message.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

SomeOne can pointed out where my mistake is, and also for the line "Dim mailServerName As String = "mail.hotmail.com" " I put " mail" because Don't know exactly how to get my localmail servername. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be sending mail through smtp.live.com.  See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/hotmail/send-receive-email-from-mail-client

Looks like they support secure connections on port 587 if you run into issues with your ISP blocking port 25.

Edit:

SMTP uses port 25; most residential ISPs block that port.  Yours may be doing this.  Telnet is a convenient way to test this.  My ISP is doing this, so when I try to connect I see this:

```
C:\Users\foo>telnet smtp.live.com 25
Connecting To smtp.live.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25:
 Connect failed
```

If however, I use the secure port (587):

```
C:\Users\foo>telnet smtp.live.com 587
220 BLU0-SMTP254.blu0.hotmail.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.379
0.4675 ready at  Mon, 10 Dec 2012 11:43:31 -0800
```

Note that I'm running Windows 7 and the telnet client wasn't installed, so I had to add it via Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off.

Comment: still getting error in same line Ive tried both : Dim mailServerName As String = "smtp.live.com"     and  Dim mailServerName As String = "pop3.live.com "

Comment: See the edit to my answer above (too long for a comment).  Hope that helps.